# Webpack restrict only to use ES6 modules

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Hi I am developing an application using React and Webpack and Gulp.
Webpack gives us the ability to use both CommonJS style and ES6 style.

But I want it to be consistent. I want to use only ES6 module style and want to throw an error if someone uses require syntax.

How to restrict webpack to use only one Module style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack scans your files. During this process, it uses Babel to transpile `import` statements into `require` statements, which Webpack understands. Bundled JS is output of this process. Often, it's unreadable for human.

What you should do is to use ESLint. Use some of ESLint rules/plugins.
To enforce `imports`, pick this one, for example.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import
Use it in editor or as part of build step...

Note: Webpack2 supports native `import` statements

Comment: is there any eslint plugin for forcing common js. Sorry I searched but couldn't find one.